# Excel VBA ListBox (userform) - Multiple Selection Problem with fmMultiSelectSingle

Tags: excel, vba

I actually just created my own account here because I was not able to find an answer to the problem I currently have with Excel VBA..

I am creating a Userform with a ListBox, which is being populated via an multi-dimensional array. In certain cases, the ListBox is also repopulated after clicking on the ListBox, for example in a new row of that List (which automatically leads to a click-event).

Referring to the headline of my question, I discovered that when clicking on a new row of the list, both the previous and the selected row are underlined (i.e. "clicked", even though the MultiSelect option of the ListBox is set to "0-fmMultiSelectSingle"). If I request the .ListIndex Value, it just shows me the value of the previous row (not of the now new selected row).

The biggest problem though is the repopulation of the ListBox, which only (!)does not seem to work when clicking (and creating this multiselection) in a new row of the list.

I provided an example code of my situation. Naturally, my code is much more complex so I tried to shorten it up to the main aspects. I would love to send you guys a screenshot of my userform, but the data is sensible (I hope you understand my problem anyways).

The Question: Is there a solution or sufficient workaround to populate the ListBox in a situation, where -by a Click-Event-, you choose a new row in the ListBox?

Thank you in advance for your kind help. I have been trying and searching for quite some time now; maybe somebody has faced a similar problem before!

-Graf_Rasen

```vb
Sub ListBox_Click()

intListIndex = Userform.ListBox.ListIndex

'When evaluating intListIndex in combination with clicking in a new row of 'the ListBox (which executes "Sub ListBox_Click"), intListIndex merely returns the value of the previously selected ListIndex 

'defaults ListIndex, needs to be done for repopulation
Userform.ListBox.ListIndex = -1

'This does not work when changing into a new row in the ListBox
Userform.ListBox.List() = arr_DataListBox

'Redefines ListIndex
Userform.ListBox.ListIndex = intListIndex

End Sub
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue. Are you sure that you are not resetting it to `fmMultiSelectMulti` via code anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot click in a "new" row in a listbox. It may look like you are selecting a new row, but really the event that fires is just the fact that you clicked the listbox. Hence the ListIndex value still shows the previous selection's index (which is actually still the current selection.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. The "multiselection" was actually just an observation I made (I thought this might have been part of the problem).
Anyhow, is there a possible workaround to repopulate a listbox in the event (listbox_click) itself? The code does not give me an error, but won't change the listbox to the adapted one..

Comment: Where does arr_DataListBox come from? Are you sure it is different from what is currently in the listbox? Also, you should add Option Explicit to the top of your module and explicitly declare variables.

Comment: Maybe I should tell a bit more about the "story" here, which I guess helps and clarifies. 
This ListBox displays client data (name, company, telephone, ....) in a multidimensional array (where each row is a client and each column is one of the above mentioned (name, company, ...). The full information of the client is not only shown in the list, but also in several textboxes within the userform. You can can edit / change the client information in the textboxes, which is saved into the multi-array and then put into the ListBox. 
...

Comment: ...
If the relationship manager is changing some client information in the textbox and then clicks on a new client in the ListBox, I run into the problem explained above. 
The (correct) new array is built and apparently put into the ListBox (the is no VBA error), but the ListBox (what you can actually see in the end) is not changed, i.e. the changes you made with the client before are not anticipated. 
I did not add "Option Explicit", but declared all Variables...

Comment: ...
(if there would not be a clear definition of the variables it would give me errors when editing client data (i.e. the ListBox) in all other cases I guess.)

Comment: So arr_DataListBox is a module level variable? Try adding DoEvents before End Sub.

Comment: No, arr_DataListBox is a Public Variable which is adapted in multiple subs. I just tried DoEvents within and after the Change event but no sucess (i.e. the ListBox is not populated by arr_DataListBox, as described above). I have more and more the feeling that you can't really change the ListBox at all within the ListBox_Click Event..

Comment: Is your Userform named "Userform"? Try changing Userform.Listbox to Me.Listbox.

Comment: I just explicity named the Userform in the Sub (i.e. Transferred the "Me"), without success. I will try to create a small model example for you to understand what is happening. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I tested this and it looks like you can't modify the list of a listbox in its own click event. I do get a run-time error "Permission denied", not sure why you weren't getting one. You may need to change your error trapping options to "Break in Class Module".

Comment: That totally would make sense. However, even after changing my error trapping options VBA does not recognize an error there. 
I guess I just have to anticipate this inability of ListBoxes and would need to generate a workaround in order to prevent the final users to run into a bug there. Thanks again!